# Tommy's Teleportation Abilities

Tags: heroes-reborn

Tommy

> (Claire Bennett's twin 16 yr old son whose real name is Nathan)

absorbed his teleportation skills from

> Hiro.

All he has to do is touch someone or something and off they go to wherever he is thinking about. My question is why must he "touch" himself in order to teleport himself? It seems totally unnecessary since his hand is already connected to his body and his teleportation abilities are largely based on his thoughts. After all,

> Hiro

just blinks when he teleports himself.

Comment: It is confusing how different his powers seem to be from Hiro's. He seems to have spacial and temporal apportation, whereas Hiro had teleportation. Hiro's powers first manifested through control of time, whereas, whether or not Tommy can stop time, that was certainly not how he first learned it. The most obvious conclusion is that his powers are external, whereas Hiro's affect "self plus 50 pounds." But why would his powers be distinct from Hiro's? My guess is that any powers he takes will be different from the original, but I don't see that pattern yet.

Comment: My guess is that it is a mental block: he doesn't feel like he is touching himself if he doesn't place his hand on some other part of his body. That still does nothing to explain why his powers are different from Hiro's, of course (or why Hiro did not have baby Parkman restore his powers, or why Tommy let Hiro take on Harris alone). Ah well. At least Claire's death got an sensible explanation, which I was not expecting.

Comment: Hiro is not Tommy's biological father. Tommy "stole" Hiro's ability just after he was born and Hiro was holding him. I guess that's his "real" ability (stealing EVO powers). If that's so, does that mean he can't be killed either (from his mom Claire)? Wait a minute, how come he doesn't steal Penny Man's powers or Molly Walker's or even Angela's clairvoyant dreaming power all who he spent time with. Now I'm getting confused what his gig is. Ugh

Comment: it's very fuzzily explained and stuff, something about him being a Pitrelli means he can steal what he touches I guess?

Comment: @fbstj: it was more along the lines that, when they figured out that Hiro lost his power, and the baby most likely got it, they should not be surprised because it is a power that many Pretelli's have (obviously not all).

Comment: @iMerchant: Hiro had Tommy in his arms for some time, while Claire had him in her body for 9 months, so we can guess he need an extended contact to steal power.

Comment: @Jonah: I think it should be turned into an answer. To support it, remember the first scene with Hiro in the original show: Hiro is in his office with Ando and try to focus to stop time. He is mimicking what he had seen in comic books and mangas. The blinking effect, and the apparent need of  touching himself, is just a way to focus his power.

Answer (score 3):

He can teleport whatever he touches to wherever he thinks of in his mind. In order to teleport himself, at least for now, he has to make contact with himself.

It is possible with time he may become more skilled and not require that, but for now, that is how it is.

**Update**

Alright, so I finally caught up and saw June 13th Part 2. On June 13, when Nathan teleports Casper and Anne Clark, and himself, he isn't touching himself to do that (he only has 2 hands).

However, he was trained by Hiro how to use his power. Since Casper took his memory of Hiro away (including all his training) he'll have to relearn how to do that.

Comment: Exactly this. All of the EVOs have needed to learn how to use their powers fully. Even knowing about his powers for years, he only recently discovered how to control the destination of the 'ported subject.

Comment: I don't think so. He had a great deal of practice, but then Penny Man erased his memories, leaving him with little knowledge of even his own past, let alone his abilities. Before that happened, he could even send people through time.

Comment: Tommy touching himself in order to teleport has nothing to do with his power. It is "the Hollywood effect". meaning it is for us stupid viewers so we know that he is teleporting. Coz the idiot execs and producers dont think that We the audience are smart enough to figure out that when Tommy teleports. Same as when Hiro does it. He closes his eyes and bobs his head. Nothing to do with his ability at all, visual effect to show us (the idiot audience) that Hiro is about to do his thing.

Comment: can we not talk about "tommy touching himself"?

Comment: While a good part of the answer is @Cherubel's, it also makes sense for there needing to be some overt act to invoke an evo's power. Imagine if Tommy just automatically teleported himself every time he thought of some location, or if Hiro daydreamed about some event in his childhood and suddenly he was at both the time and place of the event? (Of course one could also argue that trying to make logical sense of the evos' various powers is pointless.)

Comment: @phantom42  oops... tommy touched himself again... on the latest episode i mean... :)

Comment: @Cherubel except that it was made an explicit plot point in an early episode that he didn't know he could teleport himself, and then he decided to touch his hand to his chest and try, and it "worked", so it in the script that making contact with his own body "made it work".

Answer (score 0):

I think that the producers made Tommy's powers distinctively different to hide the fact that Tommy had Hiro's powers from the beginning.

You know so what I'm implying is that if Tommy teleported with the exact same sound effects and vanishing act as Hiro from the begining the audience would have known he was a time traveller with the exact same powers as Hiro.
So to hide this until later on, the producers made his power appear different simply to not give the story away too soon..

Comment: This question is looking for an in-universe answer, though.